# Не работает счетчик очков в тестовой сборке, на устройстве (Unity2d)

Tags: c#, unity3d

В редакторе все работает корректно, но на самом устройстве счетчик не меняет значение (словно не обновляется, что-ли...)

```
public void addScore()
{
    playerScore += playerScore + 20;


}

public void Update()
{

    scoreText.text = playerScore + " Scores";
}
```

Может ли быть проблема в том, что метод addScore Выполняется другим скриптом???

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
    {
        GameObject player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        player.SendMessage("addScore", score);

        //score = score += 10;
        
        //scoreText.text = "Score:" + score + " ";

        Destroy(gameObject);


    }
}
```

Comment: Видимо это костыль (`SendMessage`) не работает на устройстве.

Comment: Тоже начал так подумывать. К тому же девайс китайскай, с кастомным по. Буду пробовать на других устройствах.

Comment: Вопрос открыт. Не работает на остальных девайсах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим способом:

```
void Start()
{
    rb.velocity = transform.up * speed;
    ScoreH = GameObject.Find("ScoreHolder");
    
    
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
    {

        ScoreH.GetComponent<ScoreMan>().score += 10;

        if (ScoreH.GetComponent<ScoreMan>().score > ScoreH.GetComponent<ScoreMan>().highScore)
        {
            ScoreH.GetComponent<ScoreMan>().highScore = ScoreH.GetComponent<ScoreMan>().score;
        }
        
        explosion();


    }
}
```